# How to process dynamic fields at run time in Django

Tags: python, django, types

I am developing a dynamic form based on user selection. It is a two-staged process: first the user selects from a list of radio buttons and depending on that selection, the user will be presented with appropriate form fields. I know how to do that using type, but I am using 2 different forms (1 for initial selection and 1 for the custom form fields), and 2 different views.
I have two questions:
1) is it right to separate these 2 forms and there views?
2) once the user has filled the 2nd (custom) form, how can I know at run time which fields
   were presented to her in order to create the object and save it into the DB?

```
class SelectionForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Fruit.objects.filter(...)
                                     widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                     initial='')

# views.py
def review(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SelectionForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user_choice = form.cleaned_data['choice']

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/new_order/%s' % (user_choice))
    else:
        form = SelectionForm()

    return render_to_response( '/new_order.html', {'form': form} )

def order_fruit(request, user_choice):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        """
        make_order_form uses Python type to create a form
        depending on user_choice
        """
        form = make_order_form(request.POST, user_choice)

        if form.is_valid():
            # How to know which fields were presented to the user -
            # in order to create the Order object with the right -
            # arguments ????????????????????

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    else:
        form = make_order_form(request, user_choice)

    return render_to_response('/second_step_order.html', { 'form':form })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introspect your form. Have a look inside ‘form.fields‘ or ‘form.cleaned_data‘.

Comment: I thought I had to introspect base_fields. Or what do you think?

Comment: Use `form.fields` -- `base_fields` is the class-wide definition of the fields. The form's `__init__` method could change the instance's fields.

Comment: method make_order_form returns the following: `return type('OrderForm', (forms.BaseForm,), {'base_fields':fields})` So when I try to introspect form.fields it causes an error saying: type object 'OrderForm' has no attribute 'fields'. But it doesn't complain about form.base_fields. I think it is logical, since now base_fields holds the set of fields.

Comment: Form classes have a `base_fields` attribute. Form instances have a `fields` attribute as well. When you write `form = make_order_form(request.POST, user_choice)`, the lowercase `form` suggests that it returned a form instance, not the form class.